# RecyclerView not being updated with [WIFI DIRECT] discovery

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, wifip2p

I have a `database(SQLite)` with specific "device names" and will be added to a `RecyclerView` while changing the `TextView` to Online/Offline depending on the device status.

Devices status are determined when I do an `onClickListener` of a button running this:

```
refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Scanning for devices",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Scanning failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PeerListListener:

```
  WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
            loadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)){
                peers.clear();
                peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

                deviceNameArray = new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                deviceArray     = new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                int index       = 0;
                int dbindex;

                //loadingBar.setMax(deviceDetails.size());
                //loadingBar.setProgress(0);

                for(WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList()){
                    deviceNameArray[index] = device.deviceName;


                    System.out.printf(deviceNameArray[index]);


                    deviceArray[index]     = device;
                    for(dbindex = 0;dbindex<deviceDetails.size();dbindex++) {
                        if(!deviceDetails.get(dbindex).getStatus().equals("lock") || !deviceDetails.get(dbindex).getStatus().equals("maintenance")) {
                            if (deviceDetails.get(dbindex).getDeviceNo().equals(deviceNameArray[index])) {
                                deviceDetails.get(dbindex).setStatus("online");
                            } else {
                                deviceDetails.get(dbindex).setStatus("offline");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    index++;
                    //loadingBar.setProgress(index);
                }
                mAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(UserMain.this,deviceDetails);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

//                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,deviceNameArray);
//                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            if(peers.size() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Device Found..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            loadingBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };
```

I tried printing the deviceNameArray and the devices do show up on the console name but the `RecycleView` isn't updated at all.

Part of my RecyclerView Custom Adapter:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public DeviceAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.user_main_card,parent,false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DeviceAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.deviceNo.setText("No." +deviceDetails.get(position).getDeviceNo());

    if(deviceDetails.get(position).getStatus().equals("online")) {
        holder.deviceStatus.setText("ONLINE");
    }else if(deviceDetails.get(position).getStatus().equals("offline") || deviceDetails.get(position).getStatus().equals("maintenance")){
        if(deviceDetails.get(position).getStatus().equals("offline")){
            holder.deviceStatus.setText("OFFLINE");

        }else if(deviceDetails.get(position).getStatus().equals("maintenance")){
            holder.deviceStatus.setText("MAINTENANCE");

        }
    }



    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(deviceDetails.get(position).getStatus().equals("offline") || deviceDetails.get(position).getStatus().equals("maintenance")) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, deviceDetails.get(position).getDeviceName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(deviceDetails.get(position).getStatus().equals("online")){
                ((UserMain)mContext).connect(deviceDetails.get(position).getDeviceNo());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried using:

`mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

But it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this things..

```
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

when you want to refresh or your list is update any modification then only put this line for refresh recycler view..

```
      if(mAdapter!=null){ 
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```